# Is there a way to set a TOTAL message number limit in a RabbitMQ queue? x-max-length doesn't take into account the unacked messages

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, amqp, kombu

I need a queue with limited message inside considering not only message in queue but also the unacked ones. Is there a way to configure this server side? If yes is it possible using kobu as library?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states that queue length uses the count of ready messages: https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html